# Need the Xpath for img id="EngineImg"

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to create the Xpath for an image.I need to click on the image and it will show some information.In order to click on the image I need the xpath of the Image with the details : img id="EngineImg".Following HTML code contains more details:

```
 <table class="level4" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="enginestatus" id="EngineStatusTD" noWrap="">
        <img id="EngineImg" onmouseover="EngineOnMouseEnter(event)" onmouseout="EngineOnMouseLeave(event)" onmousemove="EngineOnMouseMove(event)" onclick="WebStatus(false)" src="http://vaim1-apt-120/tpe/modules/site/img/engineon.gif" />
       </td>
       <td noWrap="">
        Welcome, <span class="un">ABC</span>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the XPath you are looking for is:

```
//img[@id="EngineImg"]
```

And in English this says, find all img elements in the document from the route element that have an ID attribute with a value of EngineImg.

Word of warning though, if the document you are parsing is large you might want to target the element more closely, "//" can we very inefficient in extremely large documents as it has to parse the full tree.